# Find new proportional dimensions of an image in PHP

Tags: php, image, getimagesize

I have a site and I want to upload an image and resize it because I have to put it into a div with a certain dimension.

For example my max-width is 200px and max-height is 100px

I want to upload the image and check width and height, if they are bigger than the max-width or max-height I want to find the size of the image to stay inside that div.

How can I resize proportionally the size of the image?
I only want to find new width and new height in base of my div 200px*100px

This is my script:

```
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
            {
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($tmp);
                if($width>200){
                    //too large I want to resize
                }
                if($height>100){
                    //too height I want to resize
                }
                echo(base_url().$path.$actual_image_name);
            }
```

Comment: Are you asking a Maths question? You want to know how to work out ratios?

Comment: I would recommend to use jQuery to resize images...this will put a lot of work on your server...I mean it's okay to have one picture but what if you have them more...

Comment: I can't use jQuery in this context because I have to manage in different mode this image @user123_456

Comment: check this article then: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/ is this helpful?

Comment: Yes and no, I want to know if there is a method to resize proportionally the size @F4r-20

Comment: There is no method that I know of, but the math is very simple.

Comment: if you can explain it if is possible :) @F4r-20

Comment: in the script that I have posted a link you have explained a image resizing including preservation of the proportions.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function below to stay inside a bounding box. EG 200x200. Just send in the filelocation and the max width and height. It will return an array where `$ar[0]` is the new width and `$ar[1]` is the new height.

Its written out in full so you can understand the math.

```
<?php
function returnSize($maxW,$maxH,$img) {
    $maxW = ($maxW>0 && is_numeric($maxW)) ? $maxW : 0;
    $maxH = ($maxH>0 && is_numeric($maxH)) ? $maxH : 0;

    // File and new size
    if (!file_exists($img)) {
        $size[0]=0;
        $size[1]=0;
        return $size;
    }

    $size = getimagesize($img);

    if ($maxW>0 && $maxH>0) {
        if ($size[0]>$maxW) {
            $scaleW = $maxW / $size[0];
        } else {
            $scaleW = 1;
        }

        if ($size[1]>$maxH) {
            $scaleH = $maxH / $size[1];
        } else {
            $scaleH = 1;
        }

        if ($scaleW > $scaleH) {
            $fileW = $size[0] * $scaleH;
            $fileH = $size[1] * $scaleH;
        } else {
            $fileW = $size[0] * $scaleW;
            $fileH = $size[1] * $scaleW;
        }

    } else if ($maxW>0) {
        if ($size[0]>$maxW) {
            $scaleW = $maxW / $size[0];
        } else {
            $scaleW = 1;
        }

        $fileW = $size[0] * $scaleW;
        $fileH = $size[1] * $scaleW;

    } else if ($maxH>0) {
        if ($size[1]>$maxH) {
            $scaleH = $maxH / $size[1];
        } else {
            $scaleH = 1;
        }

        $fileW = $size[0] * $scaleH;
        $fileH = $size[1] * $scaleH;

    } else {
        $fileW = $size[0];
        $fileH = $size[1];
    }

    $size[0] = $fileW;
    $size[1] = $fileH;

    return $size;
}
?>
```

Comment: Great with this function is more clear the math of resize and I can make all! Thanks a lot +1

Answer (score 1):

This is the very basics of working out the ratio (keep persistent scale):

```
if($width>200){
    $percentage = (200/$width)*100; //Work out percentage
    $newWidth = 200; // Set new width to max width
    $newHeight = round($height*$percentage); //Multiply original height by percentage
}
else if($height>100){
    $percentage = (100/$height)*100; //Work out percentage
    $newHeight = 100; // Set new height to max height
    $newWidth = round($width*$percentage); //Multiply original width by percentage
}
```

I used `round()` to ensure that you receive integer-only new dimensions

Comment: Thanks this works but I think is better the function of Hugo, but thanks for your help +1 for the solution

Comment: Consider an image with a width of 800 and a height of 200. Now the first if will change the `$newWidth` and `$newHeight` values to something that fits (200x50) because the percentage is 25%. But your second if will change it again to something that doesnt. Your `$newWidth` value will be 400px (400x100) because the percentage with height is only 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the options...

First one: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

and the second one: http://www.sitepoint.com/image-resizing-php/   - all the math work is already done